# Problem with simple laplacian equation

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

I would like to solve the following PDE:
$$ 
\partial_x^2 u + \partial_y^2 u = -\frac{2 x^2 (x^2-y^2)}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^2}
$$
The right side comes from $ x^2 \partial_x^2 \log(x^2 +y^2) $. Switching the polar coordinates, the right side is deceptively simple:
$$
-2 \cos(\theta)^2 \cos(2 \theta) 
$$
In polar coordinates, the laplacian is:
$$
\partial_r^2 + \frac{1}{r}\partial_r + \frac{1}{r^2} \partial_\theta^2
$$
so it seems as though it should be fairly simple to find a solution. If I assume $ u(r, \theta) $ is like $ r^2 F(\theta) $, and try to solve for theta, I get something that is not periodic in $ \theta $. I am not sure if there is nonetheless a way to extract a meaningful solution. I'm at a bit of a loss for any other approaches. Any suggestions?

Edit: For $ F(\theta) $, I used mathematica to get:
$$
F(\theta) = \frac{1}{24} (-3 - 3 \cos(2 \theta) + \cos(4 \theta) - 6 \theta \sin(2 \theta))
$$
Plus of course any homogenous solution. It is the $ \theta \sin (2 \theta) $ term that makes me so sad.

Comment: I've edited to add in what I got.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's not forget that for many purposes, logarithm is a monomial of degree $0$. That is, we should consider $r^2\log r$ alongside with $r^2$. Letting
$$u(r)=r^2F(\theta)+r^2\log r\,G(\theta) \tag1$$
we arrive at the system 
$$F''+4F+4G=-2\cos^2 \theta \, \cos 2\theta,\qquad G''+4G=0 \tag2$$
Solving these, we get a bunch of constants. One of them allows us to get rid of $\theta\sin 2\theta$; specifically, $$F(\theta)=\frac{1}{24} \cos4\theta, \qquad 
 G(\theta)=-\frac14\cos 2\theta \tag3$$ if I got the computations right.

---

Remark: this example shows that solution of $\Delta u=f$ with bounded $f$ does not have locally bounded second-order derivatives in general. (E.g., $u_{rr}$ is unbounded here.) This is in contrast to the fact that for $1<p<\infty$ having $\Delta u\in L^p$ implies $u\in W_{\rm loc}^{2,p}$. Put another way, we witness the failure of the [Riesz transforms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_transform) to preserve $L^\infty$ the way they preserve $L^p$ for $1<p<\infty$.

But if $\Delta u$ was Hölder- or Dini-continuous, we would have $u\in C^2$.

Comment: (Cameron Williams had a right idea from the beginning, which I first rejected and then used. Thanks! :)

Comment: But your idea cannot find the general solution, while the mine one does.

Comment: Thank you. This is some what mind blowing to me. I am struggling to understand why one would try $ r^2 \log(r) $. I would never have thought to do that! Why did you? I missed Cameron Williams' comment.

Comment: @user86432 Cameron suggested general separated form $R(r)F(\theta)$. (As an aside, this would not work directly: the solution is not separated at all, it's the sum of two such products.) As for logarithm: you mentioned it in your post, did not you? Also, notice that Laplacian is discontinuous at the origin,  which means the solution $u$ cannot be $C^2$ smooth there. So it had to have something not as nice as $r^2$...  Finally, $r^2\log r$ is a well-known function: it's the fundamental solution of the [biharmonic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biharmonic_equation).

Comment: Your edit is interesting. I had thought that for u satisfying $ \Delta u =  x^n \partial_x^2 \log(x^2 + y^2) $, with larger n, u  will become increasingly regular.

Comment: @user86432 I think it will be increasingly regular: about as regular as $x^{n}\log (x^2+y^2)$ itself. This is what we see here with $n=2$.

Comment: Yes I think you are right. In fact, I think that for $ n = 3 $ since in this case the right side is like $ r \cos(\theta)^2 \cos(2 \theta ) $, which I think is holder, yes?Thank you for your help ( I wish there were some better way then to just say "thank you," which is meaningless after some time.)

Comment: @user86432 Well, you could register your account, which would give you the ability to vote on posts such as mine... The SE way of thanking people is voting up their posts.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\begin{cases}p=x+iy\\q=x-iy\end{cases}$ ,

Then $\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial p}\dfrac{\partial p}{\partial x}+\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial q}\dfrac{\partial q}{\partial x}=\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial p}+\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial q}$

$\dfrac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial p}+\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial q}\right)=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial p}\left(\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial p}+\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial q}\right)\dfrac{\partial p}{\partial x}+\dfrac{\partial}{\partial q}\left(\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial p}+\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial q}\right)\dfrac{\partial q}{\partial x}=\dfrac{\partial^2u}{\partial p^2}+\dfrac{\partial^2u}{\partial pq}+\dfrac{\partial^2u}{\partial pq}+\dfrac{\partial^2u}{\partial q^2}=\dfrac{\partial^2u}{\partial p^2}+2\dfrac{\partial^2u}{\partial pq}+\dfrac{\partial^2u}{\partial q^2}$

$\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}=\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial p}\dfrac{\partial p}{\partial y}+\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial q}\dfrac{\partial q}{\partial y}=i\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial p}-i\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial q}$

$\dfrac{\partial^2u}{\partial y^2}=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(i\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial p}-i\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial q}\right)=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial p}\left(i\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial p}-i\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial q}\right)\dfrac{\partial p}{\partial y}+\dfrac{\partial}{\partial q}\left(i\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial p}-i\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial q}\right)\dfrac{\partial q}{\partial y}=-\dfrac{\partial^2u}{\partial p^2}+\dfrac{\partial^2u}{\partial pq}+\dfrac{\partial^2u}{\partial pq}-\dfrac{\partial^2u}{\partial q^2}=-\dfrac{\partial^2u}{\partial p^2}+2\dfrac{\partial^2u}{\partial pq}-\dfrac{\partial^2u}{\partial q^2}$

$\therefore\dfrac{\partial^2u}{\partial p^2}+2\dfrac{\partial^2u}{\partial pq}+\dfrac{\partial^2u}{\partial q^2}-\dfrac{\partial^2u}{\partial p^2}+2\dfrac{\partial^2u}{\partial pq}-\dfrac{\partial^2u}{\partial q^2}=-\dfrac{2\left(\dfrac{p+q}{2}\right)^2\left(\left(\dfrac{p+q}{2}\right)^2-\left(\dfrac{p-q}{2i}\right)^2\right)}{(pq)^2}$

$4\dfrac{\partial^2u}{\partial pq}=-\dfrac{2\times\dfrac{(p+q)^2}{4}\left(\dfrac{(p+q)^2}{4}+\dfrac{(p-q)^2}{4}\right)}{p^2q^2}$

$\dfrac{\partial^2u}{\partial pq}=-\dfrac{(p+q)^2((p+q)^2+(p-q)^2)}{32p^2q^2}$

$\dfrac{\partial^2u}{\partial pq}=-\dfrac{2(p+q)^2(p^2+q^2)}{32p^2q^2}$

$\dfrac{\partial^2u}{\partial pq}=-\dfrac{(p^2+2pq+q^2)(p^2+q^2)}{16p^2q^2}$

$\dfrac{\partial^2u}{\partial pq}=-\dfrac{p^4+2p^3q+2p^2q^2+2pq^3+q^4}{16p^2q^2}$

$\dfrac{\partial^2u}{\partial pq}=-\dfrac{p^2}{16q^2}-\dfrac{p}{8q}-\dfrac{1}{8}-\dfrac{q}{8p}-\dfrac{q^2}{16p^2}$

$u(p,q)=f(p)+g(q)+\dfrac{p^3}{48q}-\dfrac{p^2\ln q}{16}-\dfrac{pq}{8}-\dfrac{q^2\ln p}{16}+\dfrac{q^3}{48p}$

$u(x,y)=f(x+iy)+g(x-iy)+\dfrac{(x+iy)^3}{48(x-iy)}-\dfrac{(x+iy)^2\ln(x-iy)}{16}-\dfrac{x^2}{8}-\dfrac{y^2}{8}-\dfrac{(x-iy)^2\ln(x+iy)}{16}+\dfrac{(x-iy)^3}{48(x+iy)}$

Comment: Do you want to clarify the meaning of $\ln(x+iy)$ in punctured unit disk? It does not have a single-valued branch there.

Comment: Indeed, it looks like that term is like the $ \theta \sin(\theta) $ that was problematic for me.